# How to check {{message}} == "sometext" to display certain image

Tags: javascript, python, image

I have been looking into how to implement django to code to check  {{message}} == "sometext" for my code. Currently there is an input to type in text on one page which display one another but I am having problems to get the input of the user to match a certain image to display on another page.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "images/150.png";
    var img2 = document.createElement("img2");
    img2.src = "images/005.png";
    var img2 = document.createElement("img2");
    img2.src = "images/005.png";
    var img3 = document.createElement("img3");
    img3.src = "images/008.png";
    if({{message.get()}}== "Mewtwo"){
    var src = document.getElementById("image1");
    src.appendChild(img);


    if({{message.get()}}== "Charmeleon"){
    var src = document.getElementById("image1");
    src.appendChild(img2);

    if({{message.get()}}== "Warturtle"){
    var src = document.getElementById("image1");
    src.appendChild(img3);
    } })
```

Can someone offer advice on how this could be approached?

Answer (score 1):

You are not quoting the message value here, you are generating text like `if(Warturtle=="Warturtle"){`.

You'll need to apply quoting, but to do so sanely I recommend you use JSON; that format is a subset of JavaScript and produces valid JavaScript literals.

You'll need to do so in your view (using `json.dumps()`), or you could use this [Django snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/201/) and do it straight in the template (no need to call serializers.serialize in the annotate method):

```
if({{message.get()|jsonify}} =="Warturtle"){
```

Comment: Hello I have tried adding what you advised but I am currently getting "TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse some characters: message.get|()||jsonify"  http://pastebin.com/65ZfqhC3  Can you offer advice to why this may be the case?

Comment: @user2374930: you need to install the Django snippet I link to for `|jsonify` to work.

Comment: Hello, I do have it part of my code  http://pastebin.com/9GtSj8gJ could this be due to issues regarding with the js or python.

Comment: You are not just using Django there; you are using a different templating engine altogether. The snippet only works for *Django's* templating engine. You will have to supply you template with a jsonified value created in you python handler instead.